# White ring around my analog photos

Tags: film, olympus, superzoom

I bought a used Olympus superzoom 800s camera and this was the first time that I have used it.

There is a white ring around most of the exposed negatives and I would like to know what it is and what can I do to fix it.

Here are some pictures:

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have some sort of filter on the front of the lens? That looks a lot like bad reflections from a filter. The ring would be from the frame of the filter, and the white haze over significant portions of the pictures themselves would be from the glass of the filter.

Comment: @twalberg I dont think so? how can I tell?

Comment: Also in night photos with flash it doesn't appear!

Comment: Which makes it even more likely that what you're seeing is reflections off either a filter attached to the front of the lens, or some part of the front of the lens itself.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have photographs made in quick succession?  This looks like light leaking into the camera, possibly unrelated to taking actual photographs.  If indeed unrelated, photographs in the middle of a sequence would be comparatively unaffected, and having the camera in the dark (case, night) would also help.  It would be one explanation for your flash photographs being fine.  Another would be a light leak in the lens which would require the shutter to be open for the problem.  If flash photographs turn out fine, it might just be that there is no significant amount of direct light from the flash pointed towards the light leak.

The first photograph also has a light bar on the left side of the photograph.  That can point to stuttering shutter action.  So does the second.  The third appears to have that bar along the bottom (so likely there was a change between portrait and landscape orientation).  Flash photographs show shutter problems different from normal photographs.

The circles, however, are not a shutter problem.  If you are lucky, it's just that the lens is improperly mounted and taking it off and on and properly locking it is enough to fix *that* problem.

Comment: @user85850 hey, you're right the middle ones in a quick succession are unaffected and fine. so as the night ones
how do i fix the light leak? it's a compact camera - olympus superzoom 800s i don't think i can umount the lens

thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Makes you wonder why the original owner was selling it...

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah and it was 15 € i think i was scammed. so should i just get another...?

Comment: @Inez the camera isn't really worth anything. I'd keep it handy for the effect (never know when you want to get artsy - you could even experiment by shining a light onto various sides of the camera). And for non-light-leaked photos...you need to get a new camera. Be aware that old P&S's like this are all suspect as they're aging devices that have likely never been serviced.

Comment: @Hueco so sad today. but great ideas though. do you recommend any point and shoots? it's just for festivals and summer vacations, nothing much

Comment: If your budget is ~$15, you could just buy a disposable each time you need it. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Inez eBay. Lots of cameras in really good condition from Japanese sellers (https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEAR-MINT-in-CASE-Ricoh-R1-Point-and-Shoot-35mm-Film-Camera-From-JAPAN-368/383041867597?hash=item592f130f4d:g:c8QAAOSwhn5dJaiG and https://www.ebay.com/itm/Excellent-Pentax-Zoom-60-AF-Point-Shoot-Film-Camera-From-Japan-TESTED/153479377547?hash=item23bc15728b:g:jlgAAOSwtLRc0bnA for example). Again, though, that even if you found one in an unopened box - it's still a mechanical device. Lubricants get gummy, batteries may leak, etc.

Comment: But, because they're so cheap - they aren't worth fixing in most cases (you spend easily $250+ on repairs). So, treat them like disposables. Buy 'em, use them until they die, repeat. That being said, an excellent condition camera from the 90's or early 2000's should last you a good decade or two.

Comment: I bet it's a retractable lens, and a light seal around where the lens retracts has given up, hence the circular artifact.